# what is wrong with the logic of my code? 

Tags: c#, datetime

i need to find the oldest and youngest student. the end user has to enter the bday into a string.

```
DateTime young = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime old = DateTime.MinValue;

foreach (var d in students)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(d.dob);
        int result = DateTime.Compare(young, dt);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            old = dt;
        }

        if (result > 0)
        {
            young = dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("the youngest age is {0}",young);
Console.WriteLine("the oldest age is {0}", old);
```

There is something wrong with the logic and I'm unable to get the exact output.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this part:

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(young, dt);
if (result < 0)
{
    old = dt;
}
```

Does that look right to you? Should you really be adjusting the *oldest* value based on whether the candidate value is earlier than the *youngest* value?

Also:

- The operator overloads for comparisons of `DateTime` values can make code like this *much* simpler.
- Using `earliest` and `latest` would make it clearer than `oldest` and `youngest`; the oldest person is the one with the earliest birthday, but in terms of *dates*, early and late make more sense
- Your initial values for `young` and `old` are the same... think about whether that's really what you wanted. (Hint: you're trying to represent upper and lower bounds for values. If those start off as the *same* value, you're in trouble...)

Comment: i thought i could calculate the age in each instance and compare instead... this was what i came up with..

Comment: DateTime nw = DateTime.Now;

                                        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ma.dob);



                                        TimeSpan span = nw.Subtract(dt);
                                        int age = span.Days;

Answer (score 2):

there is something missing there you assigned `int result = DateTime.Compare(young, dt);`
 I think problem related with wrong assign...you need to check younger older

```
try
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(d.dob); // and what is dob ?
    int result = DateTime.Compare(young, dt);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        old = dt;
    }

    if (result > 0)
    {
        young = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: this snippet is part of a program where the end user is to enter the students name, date of birth, class and total marks.Here dob is an object of the student class.

Answer (score 1):

you need to compare dt with old (if its older) and compare it to young (if its younger).

```
DateTime young = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime old   = DateTime.MaxValue;
foreach (var d in students)
{
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(d.dob);
 old = old < dt ? old : dt;
 young = young > dt ? young : dt;
}
 Console.WriteLine("the youngest age is {0}", young);
 Console.WriteLine("the oldest age is {0}", old);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( dt < young )
{
   young = dt;
}

if ( old < dt )
{
   old = dt
}
```

Comment: while debugging i realised that the string is not getting converted to the datetime.how do i rectify that?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime mv = dOb;

```
                    string oldname=sName;
                    string youngname=sName;




                    foreach (var mo in students)
                    {
                        int result = DateTime.Compare(mo.dob, mv);

                        if (result == -1)
                        {
                            mv = mo.dob;
                            oldname = mo.name;
                        }

                        if (result == 1)
                        {
                            mv = mo.dob;
                            youngname = mo.name;
                        }
                    }


                    Console.WriteLine("the youngest student is: {0}", youngname);
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("the oldest student is: {0}", oldname);
                    Console.WriteLine();
```